# LLVM Intermediate representation: fptoui vs. fptosi

Tags: c++, c, clang, llvm

I'm having trouble understanding the difference between the LLVM-IR Instructions "fptosi ... to" and "fptoui ... to".

I wrote a example program to better understand the semantics of these instructions.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    double d = -3.5 - 4;
    unsigned int ui = (unsigned int) d;
    int si = (int) d;

    printf("unsigned %u, 0x%x\n", ui, ui);
    printf("signed   %i, 0x%x\n", si, si);      
    return 0;    
}
```

As expected clang generates these two kinds of instructions

```
...
%5 = fptoui double %4 to i32
store i32 %5, i32* %ui, align 4
%6 = load double* %d, align 8
%7 = fptosi double %6 to i32
store i32 %7, i32* %si, align 4
...
```

When running the program output is:

```
unsigned 4294967289, 0xfffffff9
signed -7, 0xfffffff9
```

which means, both instructions produce the same value (only in one case the value is later interpreted as signed whereas the other is interpreted as unsigned)

The LLVM IR documentation states:

> The ‘fptoui‘ instruction converts its floating point operand into the
>   nearest (rounding towards zero) unsigned integer value.

Isn't the nearest unsigned integer value for a negative double 0?
Does anyone know in which cases these instructions have different semantics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Casting a negative floating point value to an unsigned type results in undefined behavior in C and C++, and I believe the intent is the same for `fptoui`.

I believe it ought to be specified with something like the following:

> The 'fptoui' instruction converts its floating point operand into the nearest (rounding towards negative infinity) integer value. If the value cannot be represented by `ty2`, the results are undefined.

It might be good to ask this on the llvm mailing list to get more authoritative clarification.